# How do you find the center-point of the intersection/overlap between two triangles in 2D?

Tags: math, collision-detection, computational-geometry

For context, I am attempting to resolve collision-details in a 3D physics engine. The following is taking place within a 2D projection onto the separating-plane of two convex shapes.

I have two triangles, let's call them A and B. They are stored as a set of 3 points (eg. A1, A2, A3). I already know that these two triangles overlap. How can I determine a point 'P' that is in roughly the center of that overlap?

The best I could think of is trying to find the intersection of the 6 lines, then, depending upon which intersections existed, including any number of points from either of the triangles. The points selected, along with the intersection-points, could then form a polygon, which I could then find the center of.
However, I know that this would be a significant amount of computation, and given this is to be used in a real-time context, I would like to find a better method.

Below is an example of what I am referring to:
[image: two triangles intersecting with a small region of overlap, and a point P in the center of the overlap]

Comment: If you know they overlap, do you know the intersection points? You need to create a polygon of the overlap area, and then find the centroid of it.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou No, I do not. They were generated as the last-step of an EPA pass, meaning the origin of the minkowski space when projected along the collision normal lies within the combined triangle; Since the hulls are convex, this means that when these triangles are projected onto the normal-plane, they must also overlap.

Comment: By the separating axis principle, if you plug the coordinates of every vertex of one triangle in the equations of the sides of the other and conversely, you can prove that there is no intersection. From this I conjecture that you cannot solve your problem using less than six comparisons, involving some 2x2 determinants.

Comment: How do you know that the triangles overlap ? Maybe there is some useful data/property in the way you reach this conclusion that could be reused to get a faster solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides renowned algorithms for finding the intersection of two convex polygons (general terms than triangle) like [the Toussaint algorithm](https://www.bowdoin.edu/%7Eltoma/teaching/cs3250-CompGeom/spring17/Lectures/cg-convexintersection.pdf) (with [java implementation](https://www.swtestacademy.com/intersection-convex-polygons-algorithm/) and [original paper of the method](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=79179F8DF89C078B12B7AD64D9F36AED?doi=10.1.1.50.7083&rep=rep1&type=pdf)), you can use the algorithm of [this paper](https://web.mst.edu/%7Echaman/home/pubs/2015WimoTriangleTrianglePublished.pdf) (A Triangle-Triangle Intersection Algorithm) to find the intersection area between two triangles.

Now, as the intersection of two convex objects is convex, you can easily compute the centroid of the intersection using [this formula](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82275999.pdf) based on the vertices of the intersection area that have been obtained from one of the above algorithms.

Comment: You seem to like overkill solutions. For triangles, the Toussaint algorithm will be more costly than "brute force" and way more complex to implement. The Triangle-Triangle paper adds a layer of complexity because it addresses the 3D problem. I see no good reason to prefer the perimeter centroid over the vertices centroid, which is easier to compute.

Comment: Dear @YvesDaoust, you're right. However,  it's not required to implement the Toussaint from scratch. There are many good libraries and implementations for that (as I've referred to one of them as an example). By the way, it is a correct solution, but in your mind the hard one.

Also, I think it's an opinion-based discussion, as I prefer Toussiant because of its generalizability, and I implemented it in a reasonable time.

Comment: The OP is asking an efficient, real-time solution. Not a sledgehammer.

Answer (score 0):

The Toussaint algorithm is less easy than it seems, and is complete overkill for two triangles. I would use the Sutherland–Hodgman clipping algorithm . It will take three passes over one of the triangles and output from three to six vertices forming a convex polygon.

The average of the vertices will be inside that polygon. You can even compute the centroid of the area by an extension of the shoelace formula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_polygon

To simplify some computations, you can start by applying a change of basis such that one of the triangles be reduced to the vertices (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), so that the equations of the half-planes are simply x≥0, y≥0, 1-x-y≥0. This will make tests and intersections easier.